# How to count months with at least 1 non NaN value?

Tags: pandas

I have this df:

```
       CODE YEAR  MONTH DAY TMAX  TMIN   PP
0      130  1991    1    1  32.6  23.4  0.0
1      130  1991    1    2  31.2  22.4  0.0
2      130  1991    1    3  32.0   NaN  0.0
3      130  1991    1    4  32.2  23.0  0.0
4      130  1991    1    5  30.5  22.0  0.0
       ...   ...  ...  ...   ...   ...  ...
20118  130  2018    9   30  31.8  21.2  NaN
30028  132  1991    1    1  35.2   NaN  0.0
30029  132  1991    1    2  34.6   NaN  0.0
30030  132  1991    1    3  35.8   NaN  0.0
30031  132  1991    1    4  34.8   NaN  0.0
      ...   ...  ...  ...   ...   ...   ...
45000  132  2019    10   5  35.5   NaN  21.1
46500  133  1991    1    1  35.5   NaN  21.1
```

I need to count months that have at least 1 non NaN value in TMAX,TMIN and PP columns. If the month have all nan values that month doesn't count. I need to do this by each CODE.
Expected value:

```
   CODE  YEAR MONTH  DAY  TMAX  TMIN    PP   JANUARY_TMAX  FEBRUARY_TMAX  MARCH_TMAX  APRIL_TMAX  etc
   130  1991     1    1  32.6  23.4     0           23             25          22          27    …
   130  1991     1    2  31.2  22.4     0           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   130  1991     1    3    32   NaN     0           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   130  1991     1    4  32.2    23     0           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   130  1991     1    5  30.5    22     0           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   130  2018     9   30  31.8  21.2   NaN           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   132  1991     1    1  35.2   NaN     0           21             23          22          22    …
   132  1991     1    2  34.6   NaN     0           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   132  1991     1    3  35.8   NaN     0           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   132  1991     1    4  34.8   NaN     0           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   132  2019     1    1  35.5   NaN  21.1           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
   133  1991     1    1  35.5   NaN  21.1           25             22          22          21    …
   ...   ...   ...  ...   ...   ...   ...           NaN            NaN         NaN         NaN  NaN
```

For example: In code 130 for TMAX column, i have 23 Januarys that have at least 1 non NaN value, i have 25 Februarys that have at least 1 non NaN value, etc.

Would you mind to help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be super efficient, but here is how you can do it for one of columns, TMAX in this case.  Just repeat the process for the other columns.

```
# Count occurrences of each month when TMAX is not null
tmax_cts_long =  df[df.TMAX.notnull()].drop_duplicates(subset=['CODE', 'YEAR', 'MONTH']).groupby(['CODE', 'MONTH']).size().reset_index(name='COUNT')

# Transpose the long table of counts to wide format
tmax_cts_wide = tmax_cts_long.pivot(index='CODE', columns='MONTH', values='COUNT')

# Merge table of counts with the original dataframe
final_df = df.merge(tmax_cts_wide, on='CODE', how='left')

# Replace values in new columns in all rows after the first row with NaN
mask = final_df.index.isin(df.groupby(['CODE', 'MONTH']).head(1).index)
final_df.loc[~mask, [col for col in final_df.columns if isinstance(col, int)]] = None

# Rename new columns to follow the desired naming format
mon_dict = {1: 'JANUARY', 2: 'FEBRUARY', ...}
tmax_mon_dict = {k: v + '_TMAX' for k, v in mon_dict.items()}
final_df.rename(columns=tmax_mon_dict, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I revised the first part of the answer, so you get counts of each month, as you are hoping to get.